# Owasp Zap: False positives in the PiiScan

Tags: zap

I work a lot with OWASP Zap, and I am very satisfied. Nevertheless, I have the problem with all my scans that I always have false positives in the PiiScan area. Among other things, Googlemaps numbers, or product numbers are recognized as Visa card numbers.

I have not seen any way to prevent this, but I am looking for a way to secure the PiiScanns to get real results.

How can this be avoided within Owasp Zap?

Are there any settings to get a better PiiScann?

Answer (score 2):

The PII rule was updated in the last release to fix some issues: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/main/addOns/pscanrulesBeta/CHANGELOG.md

But we also have an open issue: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/6639 - why not comment on that or open a new issue. If we can make it more acurate without missing some valid use cases then we will.

Comment: Hello Simon first of all thank you for the quick response.


I will open a new bug with you, and describe the issue accordingly with some more background information. 

The question here, can we as a first interim solution exclude certain pages that contain product numbers, or Googlemaps values from PII scan? 

Or maybe as a solution mark whole pages accordingly that you can exclude?

Comment: We have a FAQ for that :) https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-i-handle-a-false-positive/